# How to use Moses Translator in Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika, machine-translation, moses

I am trying to use Apache Tika for machine translation in a Java project, specifically the MosesTranslator class. I have installed Moses by following the instructions given in this [link](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted).

However, in the [docs](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/api/org/apache/tika/language/translate/MosesTranslator.html) for MosesTranslator, it is given that we need to provide two variables, smtPath and scriptsPath, in the constructor.

> MosesTranslator(String smtPath, String scriptPath)

What values should be provided for these variables? It seems smtPath should be a path to some jar file for Moses, but I can't any jar file after installing Moses.